# Select few rows from a result table and achieve below output

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

I have two tables like
T1

```
 Boss     employee  
 Bran     josh 
 Bran     paul
 Bran     i-sara
 Bran     shaun
Joseph    will
Joseph    i-alex
Joseph    i-vicky
Joseph    mary
Joseph    cristi
```

T2

```
Worker    object       price
josh      bus          2
paul      car          5
i-sara    i-sara       null
Shaun     skate        3
will      football     2
i-alex    i-alex       null
mary      dino         6        
i-vicky   i-vicky      null
Cristi    bike         5
```

I need to join both tables and get the output table like mentioned below

So I have written a query like below

select boss, employee, object, price from T1 left join on T1.employee=T2.worker order by boss;

By executing the above query I'm getting below output

Output:

```
Boss     employee    object    price
Bran      josh        bus       2
Bran      paul        car       5
Bran      i-sara      i-sara    null
Bran      shaun       skate     3
Joseph    will        football  2
Joseph    i-alex      i-alex    null
Joseph    mary        dino      6
Joseph    i-vicky    i-vicky    null
Joseph    cristi      bike      5
```

I want to remove the rows which has employee or object as "i-%" from the above output table which i have got after executing the query and place them in separate column with their respectice "boss" group. And get the output table as below

```
Boss     employee  object    price  person
Bran      josh      bus       2    i-sara
Bran      paul      car       5    null
Bran      shaun     skate     3    null
Joseph    will      football  2    i-alex, i-vicky
Joseph    mary      dino      6    null
Joseph    cristi    bike      5    null
```

OR

```
Boss     employee  object    price  person
Bran      josh      bus       2    i-sara
Bran      paul      car       5    null
Bran      shaun     skate     3    null
Joseph    will      football  2    i-alex
Joseph    mary      dino      6    i-vicky
Joseph    cristi    bike      5    null
```

Can anyone help me on achieving the output which i desire?

Comment: You didn't say what are your thoughts behind the desired output.

Comment: I have edited my question. Hope my question is clear to understand

Comment: you comment before was useful for the question to be answered. You can put the same in the question as well

Comment: Added the same comment in the question as suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My take would be to use `listagg` separately for the `i-%` case,

```
select boss, employee, object, price
      ,case when rn = 1 then 
         (select listagg(t2i.worker,',') within group (order by t2i.worker)
            from t2 t2i
            join t1 t1i 
              on t1i.employee = t2i.worker
             and t1i.boss = t1.boss
           where t2i.worker like 'i-%'
          group by t1i.boss
         ) 
       end persons
from
(select boss, employee, object, price,
   row_number() over (partition by t1.boss order by null) rn
  from t1 
left join t2
  on t1.employee = t2.worker
where t1.employee not like 'i-%'
) t1
order by boss;
```

[Db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=596cacd122c3a430d34640a10f684262) for reference

Comment: Wow that was really helpful but can you please explain on how it functions.

Comment: Yes, first thing is from your base query we exclude the workers having `i-%'` cases and then , `listagg` function aggregates within a particular group with the delimiter we want which allow us to use the correlate query where we only now considered the workers with `'i-%'` case and correlate to the outer query by joining `t1i.boss=t1.boss` and finally as you want only to be displayed once I use the `row_number() ` to only display the value in the first row for each individual boss. Hope I make some sense

Answer (score 2):

Another variant:

```sql
with joined as (
   select
      boss, 
      employee, 
      object, 
      price,
      case when employee like 'i-%' then 1 else 0 end grp,
      row_number()over(partition by boss, case when employee like 'i-%' then 1 else 0 end order by employee) rn
   from T1 
        left join T2
             on T1.employee=T2.worker 
)
select
  j1.*, j2.employee as person
from joined j1
     left join joined j2
          on  j1.rn   = j2.rn 
          and j1.boss = j2.boss 
          and j2.grp=1
where j1.grp=0
order by 1,2,3;
```

As you can see, at first I created CTE `joined` where I put your original join and added a couple of columns: `grp` - 0 for usual rows, and 1 for 'i-' rows, second column is `rn` - row_number partitioned by boss and `grp` and ordered by employee - you can see it in final results as `rn` column. So we can use `boss` and `rn` to join different groups.

Full test case with sample data:

```sql
with t1( Boss,employee  ) as (
select 'Bran'  , 'josh'      from dual union all
select 'Bran'  , 'paul'      from dual union all
select 'Bran'  , 'i-sara'    from dual union all
select 'Bran'  , 'shaun'     from dual union all
select 'Joseph', 'will'      from dual union all
select 'Joseph', 'i-alex'    from dual union all
select 'Joseph', 'i-vicky'   from dual union all
select 'Joseph', 'mary'      from dual union all
select 'Joseph', 'cristi'    from dual
),t2(Worker,object,price) as (
select 'josh'   ,   'bus'     , 2    from dual union all
select 'paul'   ,   'car'     , 5    from dual union all
select 'i-sara' ,   'i-sara'  , null from dual union all
select 'shaun'  ,   'skate'   , 3    from dual union all
select 'will'   ,   'football', 2    from dual union all
select 'i-alex' ,   'i-alex'  , null from dual union all
select 'mary'   ,   'dino'    , 6    from dual union all    
select 'i-vicky',   'i-vicky' , null from dual union all
select 'cristi' ,   'bike'    , 5    from dual
)
,joined as (
   select
      boss, 
      employee, 
      object, 
      price,
      case when employee like 'i-%' then 1 else 0 end grp,
      row_number()over(partition by boss, case when employee like 'i-%' then 1 else 0 end order by employee) rn
   from T1 
        left join T2
             on T1.employee=T2.worker 
)
select
  j1.*, j2.employee as person
from joined j1
     left join joined j2
          on  j1.rn   = j2.rn 
          and j1.boss = j2.boss 
          and j2.grp=1
where j1.grp=0
order by 1,2,3;
```

Results:

```
BOSS   EMPLOYE OBJECT        PRICE        GRP         RN PERSON
------ ------- -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -------
Bran   josh    bus               2          0          1 i-sara
Bran   paul    car               5          0          2
Bran   shaun   skate             3          0          3
Joseph cristi  bike              5          0          1 i-alex
Joseph mary    dino              6          0          2 i-vicky
Joseph will    football          2          0          3

6 rows selected.
```